# Line plot with mean and SD, but data file includes missing values in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I could make line plot, but when trying to add mean and SD, it shows errors; non-numeric argument to binary operator in ggplot.

The data is in text file as below. It includes 500 individuals' data.

```
ID time1 time2 time3 time4 time5 time6 time7 time8
1 4 8 25 4 25 8 NA 9      
2 NA 56 32 5 2 69 20 4
3 84 NA NA 45 87 2 98 34
...
500 8 34 72 38 2 84 84 4
```

```
library("reshape2")
library("ggplot2")
mdf <- read.table("data.txt",header=TRUE)
mdf <- melt(mdf, id.vars="ID", value.name="Scale", variable.name="Time")
ggplot(data=mdf, aes(x=Time, y=Scale, group = ID, colour = ID))+
geom_line()+
geom_point( size=4, shape=21, fill="white")
```

So, I added as below in order to add mean and SD.

```
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Scale-sd, ymax=Scale+sd), width=.2,position=position_dodge(0.05))
```

It shows errors; non-numeric argument to binary operator in ggplot. I thought that NA is causing trouble, so I tried as below.

```
data.omit <- na.omit(mdf)
```

But it did not resolve the issue.
I tried to change mdf to numeric, but it also did not work.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have to compute the standard deviation, e.g. via `mutate(mdf, sd = sd(Scale, na.rm = TRUE))` which also takes care of the NA. geom_errorbar won't do that for you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I just  added mutate(mdf, sd = sd(Scale, na.rm = TRUE)) instead of geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Scale-sd, ymax=Scale+sd), width=.2,position=position_dodge(0.05)). but it said the same error for ggplot(data = mdf, aes(x = Time, y = Scale, group = ID, colour = ID)) + "non-numeric argument to binary operator in ggplot".

Comment: (: Soory. Shoud be more clearer. Before plotting do `mdf <- mutate(mdf, sd = sd(Scale, na.rm = TRUE))`, i.e. you add a column with sd to your df. After that geom_errorbar will work and take the sd from your df. Depending on how you would the sd be computed, by ID or by Time you probabyl have to add a group_by()

Comment: Thank you stefan! It perfectly worked!!